# stack smashing detected..while sending ICMP packet

Tags: c, icmp, stack-smash

I have written a `C` program to send an `ICMP` packet. Here is the corresponding code..

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int Seq_Num = 1;
struct icmp_header
{
unsigned char type;
unsigned char code;
unsigned short check_sum;
unsigned short id;
unsigned short seq_num;
 char msg[20];
   };

void make_icmp( struct icmp_header *I, char *msg_to_snd, int m_len )
{
I->type = 13;   //for timestamp 
I->code = 0;    // request..
I->id   = htons(713);   //some unique ID..
I->seq_num= htons(Seq_Num);
Seq_Num++;
/*computing the check sum..*/
unsigned int Sum = 0;
memset(I->msg, 0, 100);
unsigned short *ptr = (unsigned short*)I;
Sum += *ptr++;
ptr++;
Sum += *ptr++;
Sum += *ptr++;
strcpy(I->msg, msg_to_snd);

ptr = ( unsigned short*)I->msg;

int len = m_len;
if(len & 1)
    len++;

while(len >=0)
{
    Sum += *ptr++;  
    len -=2;
}   

Sum = (Sum >>16) + Sum& 0x0000ffff; /*add the carries..*/

Sum += (Sum>>16);   /*add the newly generated carries..*/

I->check_sum = ~Sum;    
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
if(argc ==1)
{
    perror("ip addr. required..\n");
    exit(1);
}


    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 1);

    if(sock==-1)
    {
        perror("sock():");
        exit(1);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in Sk;
    bzero(&Sk, sizeof(Sk));
    Sk.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &Sk.sin_addr);
    struct icmp_header Q;


        char buf[20];
        scanf("%s", buf);
        make_icmp(&Q, buf, strlen(buf));    

        if(sendto( sock, &Q, sizeof(Q), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&Sk, sizeof(Sk))<0)
        {
            perror("sendto..");
            exit(1);
        } 
        sleep(1);
    printf("sent successfully\n");


return 0;
}
```

The problem with the code is that when I run it, the icmp packet is successfully sent which i can see in `wire shark`. But at last after displaying `sent successfully` i get the following error..

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./a.out terminated
```

Please tell me what am I missing..Thanks.

Comment: where did you see such a name convention `icmp_header *I`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Size of `I->msg` is just `20`, but you're setting more than its capacity:

```
memset(I->msg, 0, 100); // 100 > 20 and it exceeds the array boundaries
```

Comment: then why doesn't it show up at that instruction itself? How come it got executed successfully?

Comment: It's undefined behavior, sometimes it run OK, and sometimes crashes.

Comment: Perhaps the _stack smashing_ check runs only on function exit - it would be really expensive to check after every instruction. If you can run it under valgrind it may confirm the exact line.

Comment: @Useless then why not after the `make_icmp` function call? why after `main()` function call?

Comment: The specific stack frame that was smashed wasn't `make_icmp`'s, even though that function did the damage. `Q` is the object you wrote past the end of, and that's on `main`'s stack frame. So, if `make_icmp` checks its own stack frame when it exits, it won't see any damage. When `main` performs the same check on its frame, it realises that `make_icmp` smashed it. NB. This is all (the stack frame layout, runtime stack smashing check etc.) _very_ platform specific. Undefined Behaviour is all you're guaranteed.